# The resolution of android emulator of SDK tools R21 is not good as the old version?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I just downloaded the latest version of **SDK Tools R21 (Revision 21.0.1)**.

Then i created **AVD for Galaxy Nexus** by Android virtual Device Management of SDK Tools R21.

But when i launched this **AVD** on both **SDK Tools R21** and **SDK Tools R11** (the old version), i saw that the **resolution of AVD of R11** is **better** than **R21**.

I did not know why the resolution is different on these version of SDK tools.

Which one is correct? I want to upgrade the SDK Tools to the latest version, but i think the emulator of the latest version is not good as the old version (R11).

I posted the images on both versions for everybody can see the difference between them. Thanks for any explanation.

[image]

[image]

**[The AVD of R21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gnxh.png)**

[image]

**[The AVD of R11 (as you can see the icons are smaller than the AVD of R21)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXNZL.png)**

[image]

Comment: Nobody got this issue? instead of buying a various real phones, i want to create emulator for various resolutions and screen sizes for testing. But the difference of resolution on latest version make me confused, i don't know which version of SDK tools i should use to create emulator correspond to correct resolution of real device.

Comment: I can't say for sure why the difference, but I *can* say that the image you posted for R21 more closely matches the icon/text size of the actual Galaxy Nexus device. Then again, if you're trying to emulate a GNexus, you might want to use a different API version. I'm pretty sure none have shipped with API 8.